# char** Array Out of Bounds Behavior in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

Could someone explain what occurs in C, for 2D arrays, when you go outside the index bounds but within the initialized memory?

For instance:

```
    char t[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {   
        printf("%i\n", t[0][i]); //prints 1 thru 6 on separate lines
    }
```

works as expected, but

```
//gcc 5.4.0

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* s[] = {".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--.."};

/*
    printf("%i\n", s); 
    printf("%i\n",(s+1));
    printf("%i\n",(s+2));
    printf("%i\n", (s+3));
    printf("%i\n", (s+4));
*/

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {   
        printf("%c\n", s[0][i]);
    }

    return 0;

/* Output:
.
-

.
.
.
-

-
.
.
-

-
.
-
-

-
-
*/
```

shows that each "string" is allocated 8 bytes of contiguous memory, but the characters do not print out contiguously as they appear in the array (morse code) - the first 2 chars are from s[0], but the last are from the end of the array.

Comment: One is a two-dimensional array, the other is an array of pointers to string literals.  There is no guarantee about the addresses of these string literals.

Comment: How does 1st code **prints 1 thru 6 on separate lines**?

Comment: In the second example, `char* s[] ` is a pointer, not an array, like in the first example.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I see now, that was careless of me. I was working a lot with 2D arrays and it just slipped my mind. Of course pointers are contiguous, but not the literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s` is not a 2D array.  You're not storing the *strings* in `s` - you're storing the *address* of the first character of each string in `s` (and on your machine, a `char *` is 8 bytes wide).  The strings themselves don't have to be adjacent in memory, such that if you walk past the end of one string, you walk into the beginning of another.

IOW, you're imagining that `s` looks like this:

```
         +---+
s[0][0]: |'.'|
         +---+
s[0][1]: |'-'|
         +---+
s[0][2]: | 0 |
         +---+
s[1][0]: |'-'|
         +---+
s[1][1]: |'.'|
         +---+
s[1][2]: |'.'|
         +---+
          ...
```

That's not the case.  What you actually have is something like this:

```
      +---+         +---+---+---+
s[0]: |   | ------> |'.'|'-'| 0 | <-------------+
      +---+         +---+---+---+               |
s[1]: |   | ---+                                |
      +---+    |    +---+---+---+---+---+       |
s[2]: |   | -+ +--> |'-'|'.'|'.'|'.'| 0 | <-----+---- not guaranteed to be adjacent
      +---+  |      +---+---+---+---+---+       |
       ...   |                                  |
             |      +---+---+---+---+---+       |
             +----> |'-'|'.'|'-'|'.'| 0 | <-----+
                    +---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Thank you John. I quickly realized this after Christian's comment.